# Centering UI elements in an Xcode Scene

Tags: xcode

I am new to Xcode. In the Designer mode the screen looks like this:

[image]

And the properties are:

[image]

When executed the result is scrunched to the upper left corner - both in Simulator and on the actual device:

[image]

I could not find any additional LayoutManager type of settings. What is supposed to be done here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is a tiny magic icon in the bottom right called `Add New Alignment Constraints`:

[image]

Here is where it is at in the bigger scheme of life:

[image]

Now it becomes clear what to do: click on both of the checkboxes:

- Horizontally in Container
- Vertically in Container

I wish these things would be included in the Menu-accessible actions instead of needing to hunt every tiny and incomprehensible icon in the gui.